# C++ template friend class does not satisfy conceptual constraints because it is an incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, friend, incomplete-type, concept

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>

template<typename T>
concept is_buffer = requires (T t) {
    { t.pointer() } -> std::same_as<char*>;
    { t.capacity() } -> std::same_as<size_t>;
    { t.rwlock() } -> std::same_as<std::shared_mutex&>;
};

template<typename Buffer>
requires is_buffer<Buffer>
class buffer_stream {
};

class shared_array_buffer {
private:
    struct meta {
        char* ptr {};
        size_t capacity {};
        std::mutex mutex {};
        std::shared_mutex rwlock{};
        int reference_count {};
    };
    meta* meta_ {};
    /* Error occured here */
    friend class buffer_stream<shared_array_buffer>;
public:
    char* pointer() {
        return meta_->ptr;
    }
    size_t capacity() {
        return meta_->capacity;
    }
    std::shared_mutex& rwlock() {
        return meta_->rwlock;
    }
};
int main() {
    shared_array_buffer buffer;
    buffer_stream<shared_array_buffer> stream;
}
```

In this code, I use the class `buffer_stream` as the friend class of `shared_array_buffer` and `unique_array_buffer`, they are all template class with concept.

The compiler says `template constraint failure for ‘template<class Buffer>  requires  is_buffer<Buffer> class buffer_stream’` because `‘t’ has incomplete type`(in class shared_array_buffer).

I wonder why the `shared_array_buffer` is an incomplete type.All the types of the member is fully defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
friend class buffer_stream<shared_array_buffer>;
```

This makes the `is_buffer` `concept` check if `shared_array_buffer` is valid, but `shared_array_buffer` is not complete that the point of the `friend` declaration, so compilation fails.

A workaround could be to delay the validation using a `static_assert` instead:

```cpp
template <typename Buffer>
class buffer_stream {
    static_assert(is_buffer<Buffer>);
};
```

---

Another option is to let `buffer_stream` inherit from the buffer type. You can then create `protected` accessors that it can use and don't need to make it a `friend`:

```cpp
class shared_array_buffer {
private:
    struct meta {
        char* ptr{};
        size_t capacity{};
        std::mutex mutex{};
        std::shared_mutex rwlock{};
        int reference_count{};
    };
    meta* meta_{};

public:
    char* pointer() { return meta_->ptr; }
    size_t capacity() { return meta_->capacity; }
    std::shared_mutex& rwlock() { return meta_->rwlock; }
};

template <typename Buffer>
    requires is_buffer<Buffer>
class buffer_stream : public Buffer {
};
```

Comment: just came to the same conclusion, but this shouldn't this technically possible by delaying friend declarations to the end of a class definition?

Comment: @0xbachmann It perhaps _should_ be possible, but unfortunately, it isn't. Very inconvenient. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has something to do with the order in which templates are instantiated and when `requires` clauses are evaluated. Removing the requires clause and replacing it by a `static_cast` seems to be a workaround:

```
template<typename Buffer>
// requires is_buffer<Buffer>             <--- this fails
class buffer_stream {
    static_assert(is_buffer<Buffer>);  // <--- this succeeds
};
```

This behaves the same for all major compilers [see demo](https://godbolt.org/z/36469hM3v).

Comment: so the friend template class is executed before the class member was fully defined?I tried to move the friend declaration to the end of the class defination and it actully have no effect.

Comment: yes, the requires clause is checked before the class is fully defined